# TypeError when adding javascript to a Freeboard widget plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a widget plugin to display a graph from a RRD file in Freeboard (https://github.com/Freeboard/freeboard).
However, when I add the javascript for handling RRDs in the plugin, I get an exception: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

If I remove the line  "./plugins/thirdparty/freeboard-jsrrd/javascriptrrd-1.1.1/src/lib/javascriptrrd.wlibs.js" in the external_scripts array in the file jsrrd.plugin.js, there is no exception.

What can I do to fix this?

Source: https://bitbucket.org/niclask/freeboard-jsrrd/src
Plugin file: plugins/thirdparty/freeboard-jsrrd/jsrrd.plugin.js

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just debug it? I mean you have the environment, you have an exception with stack trace, you have developer tools.

Comment: I have tried, But I don't understand how the framework in freeboard works.  This is the first javascript I have written...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was missing javascripts in external_scripts. Once I added the javascripts the graph works.